# Image get clipped while rotating canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas, android-imageview

I am developing an application in which I am rotating image using following code.

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image2); 
Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
    tempCanvas.rotate(-10, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2); 
tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);

mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmResult);
```

Taken from [Rotating a drawable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763103/rotating-a-drawable-in-android)

but the image get clipped from edges something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399835/how-to-rotate-textview-without-clipping-its-bounds)

I have searched the internet but I cannot resolve it. I know that i have to increase the size of bmResult.I also tried doing that but still some edges got clipped .

If any body can give me clue or solve the problem following is my Imageview xml code

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp" >

</ImageView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Alan for the answer 
I have got the solution that I just draw the image after rotating on (10,10) x,y on canvas like.

```
`tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 10, 10, null);`
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that worked for me was to set the margins to a negative number:

```
    params.setMargins(-350, -350, -350, -350);
    final ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
    img1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    linearLayoutBackground.addView(img1, params);
```

Probably not a best practice, but it did the trick in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, this code worked out for me. Try it.

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image2); 
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(-10);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), mat, true);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```